# How do I pass a variable between routes in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to pass variable from one express route to another. The variable is being incremented on a POST route and I'm trying to retrieve it on the front end via a GET route.

I've tried using express-sessions but value won't increment past the first iteration of the loop.

```
app.post('/post-route', (req, res) => {
    // data passed from form
    let data = req.body.someArray
    let variableToPass = 0;

    // render a success/landing page
    res.render('/success',{
        title: 'page title'
        data: someData
    });
    // loop
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // do something with data here
        variableToPass++;
    }
});
```

```
app.get('/get-route', (req, res) => {
    // get variable here and return to ajax request
    res.json({
      data: variableToPass
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Make it global:

```
let variableToPass = 0;

app.post("/post-route", (req, res) => {
  variableToPass = 0;
  // ...
});

app.get("/get-route", => {
  res.json({
    data: variableToPass
  });
});
```

Comment: oh man, I was sorely overthinking this! this worked, thank you!

Comment: No worries @senjutsu, always glad to help.

Comment: I hate to reopen this, but I did find a strange behavior. If I post something different on the post route at the same time or while I'm still processing an initial post request, the get route returns the variable based on the initial post request. Is there a way I could differentiate between different requests?

Comment: Yes - if they all take the same amount of time to execute, you could `push` each value into the array, then `shift` it off each time. That is a fairly difficult requirement though - maybe you could reaccept my answer (since it solved your initial problem) and ask another question.